# Airflow terminate EMR cluster

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr

I am using EMR cluster to run some job to run in parallel. Both of these job run in same cluster. I have put action_on_failure field to 'CONTINUE' so that if 1 task fails, the other should run in the cluster. I want end task which is EMRTerminateCluster to run after both these tasks gets completeted regardless of success or failure.

```
         task2 
task1 >>       >> task4
         task3
```

I want my dags to run in such a way that task4 only starts after task 2 and task3.

is there any way to this?

Comment: maybe this can help you https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/emr.html

Answer (score 0):

I am answering one of your questing on Terminating EMR Cluster, to avoid unnecessary cloud billing

- You need to set airflow Trigger rule to `all_done` in EMR terminating task-id in DAG
- task-id with `all_done` trigger-rule gets executed whether if upstream tasks got failed or succeeded.
- sample code of terminating EMR task-id

```
  terminate_emr_cluster = PythonOperator(
  task_id='terminate_emr_cluster',
  python_callable=terminate_cluster,
  op_args=['{{ ti.xcom_pull("create_emr_cluster")["JobFlowId"]}}'],
  dag=dag, 
  trigger_rule="all_done",
  )
```

took DAG code from here - https://github.com/SatadruMukherjee/Data-Preprocessing-Models/blob/main/airflow_emr_spark_s3_snowflake.py